# doAsync Kotlin-android doesn't work well

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using a callback function when async ends. but it doesn't work well :(

my case:

```
fun function1(callback : (obj1: List<ObjT1>,obj2: List<ObjT1>)-> Unit?){
    doAsync {

        //long task

        uiThread { callback(result1, result2) }
    }
}
```

the callback is called but `result1` and `result2`(lists) are empty. I checked previous the content of the list.

EDIT:
PROBLEM: my callback is a function that receives 2 objects result 1 and result2, the problem is the function callback sometimes receives the results empty, i check their content and is not empty.

Comment: I cannot find doasync or uiThread in Kotlin Android Extensions, are you using an additional library?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you've declared return type as `Unit?` but are returning two values. A quick fix would be to put `result1` and `result2` in an array.

Comment: No, my callback is a function that receives 2 objects result 1 and result2, the problem is the function callback sometimes receives the results empty, i check their content and is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Now this question is about deprecated Kotlin library.
I recommend use coroutines.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Kotlin's coroutines. Coroutines is a newer feature in Kotlin. It is still technically in it's experimental phase, but JetBrains has told us that it is very stable.
Read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

Here is some sample code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking { // runBlocking is only needed here because I am calling join below
    val job = launch(UI) { // The launch function allows you to execute suspended functions
        val async1 = doSomethingAsync(250)
        val async2 = doSomethingAsync(50)

        println(async1.await() + async2.await()) // The code within launch will 
        // be paused here until both async1 and async2 have finished
    }

    job.join() // Just wait for the coroutines to finish before stopping the program
}

// Note: this is a suspended function (which means it can be "paused")
suspend fun doSomethingAsync(param1: Long) = async {
    delay(param1) // pause this "thread" (not really a thread)
    println(param1)
    return@async param1 * 2 // return twice the input... just for fun
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.